# JavaFX - Approach for UI components and FXML Structure

Tags: javafx

I want to start an project, which seems like Folder Explorer. Could you pls guide which UI Compnoents I need to select and what will be the high level approach.

I want an Treeview at the left side and on every click on the leaf node different panel should appear.

I was planning to use FXML 8 and then write controller classes and event handlers.
I'm struck with inital design with treeview with seperator and panels.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [SceneBuilder 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html).  Go through the Oracle tutorials on SceneBuilder (thoroughly and twice).  Start to create your app:

```
File | New from Template | Complex Application
```

Use SceneBuilder to mock up the UI.  It's all just drag and drop so getting a rough outline will be simple once you have read the documentation.

Once you have a basic UI put together:

```
View | Show Sample Skeleton
```

The skeleton will outline the controller class to match your FXML.  From thereon, start writing code.  Building an application like Windows Explorer (at least of any quality) is complex and will be a bit of work; you have a long way to go - good luck ;-)